# react-hook-form formState cause useEffect run extra

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

```js
const { formState } = useForm();
const { isDirty, isValid, isSubmitted, isSubmitting, isSubmitSuccessful } = formState;
React.useEffect(() => {
  console.log('formState', { isDirty, isSubmitSuccessful, isSubmitted, isSubmitting, isValid });
}, [isDirty, isSubmitSuccessful, isSubmitted, isSubmitting, isValid]);
```

I got these logs when component mounted:

```
formState {"isDirty": false, "isSubmitSuccessful": false, "isSubmitted": false, "isSubmitting": false, "isValid": false}
formState {"isDirty": false, "isSubmitSuccessful": false, "isSubmitted": false, "isSubmitting": false, "isValid": false}
formState {"isDirty": false, "isSubmitSuccessful": false, "isSubmitted": false, "isSubmitting": false, "isValid": true}
formState {"isDirty": false, "isSubmitSuccessful": false, "isSubmitted": false, "isSubmitting": false, "isValid": true}
```

From the log can see only `isValid` changed from false to true, I expected just 2 logs but I got 4. Why is that?

Comment: you need to post more code

Comment: @IamL it is quite a large chunk of codes. But even without the rest of codes, isn't it odd enough that useEffect runs 4 times but its deps only changed once? But it reminds me I should sandbox this in a demo, will get back if I find something.

Comment: well, we can't help you if we don't know what triggers those values